# Creation of account failed, maybe because of wallet lock/unlock process

Tags: cleos, create

When i run

```
create account eosio eoseospro EOS52e5CVjeV9DbzFii6ApQBEg65A1YFvfbNyRoVr49wsFjdMqSL7 EOS52e5CVjeV9DbzFii6ApQBEg65A1YFvfbNyRoVr49wsFjdMqSL7
```

I always get an error.

> Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy
>   declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related private keys
>   inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked. Error Details:
>   transaction declares authority
>   '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have
>   signatures for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an wallet lock/unlock issue i think. The issue is you are not providing authorization to action. You can authorize this action by providing key of eosio account.

As per your issue i think you are using cleos tool to create account for that you need to check that is key of eosio added in your wallet? And compare that command(you are using) with the given example below.

```
cleos create account eosio bob YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY -p eosio
```

Comment: Mr Y,  i follow you recomendation , i made the eosio account iand works fine, thanks a lot